# How much python is necessary to use SimpleCV?

Tags: python, simplecv

I have some python knowledge but I'd never consider myself particularly fluent in the language. I've a potential machine vision project in the works that would benefit greatly from SimpleCV but I'd rather not have to be hugely fluent in python in order to actually use it from a time standpoint. It's not that I mind learning python; it's that I'd rather get the project done with and then figure out the rest of it.

Comment: Not really part of the answer, but if you want to see if simpleCV is a fit for you - take a look at http://simplecv.tumblr.com/post/19307835766/opencv-vs-matlab-vs-simplecv

Comment: This is probably too vague a question for this site, but I'd say "apparently not much". It seems like an easy to use library, and Python probably won't get in the way. It's a shame they went lowerCamelCase allTheWay though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very little. Python has great online help

Defining functions is trivial, arrays are pretty obvious. About the only python-esque thing is probably using range[] to do a loop rather than for (i=0.....)

Just like in C++ all the new stuff about iterators and lambdas looks clever but isn't necessary to get stuff done.

If you are using this for matlab type, interactive image algorithm developement then [ipython](http://ipython.org/) is a great environment. It also has a shell that can do inline image and plot display and shows the man page for each function as you type the name.